# Apple and iCloud encryption keys

Tags: ios, icloud, security, privacy

A friend of mine was arguing that Apple’s staunch pro-privacy and pro-security branding is disingenuous since they hold iCloud encryption keys.

To what extent is this true or an oversimplification?

Answer (score 2):

iCloud is an umbrella term that encompasses a number of Apple services. How Apple handles encryption for various aspects of its services is detailed here: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Most relevant is the section on Internet Services, starting on p. 49. In general, keys are tied to your device(s) which are protected by your passcode (that only you know), and hopefully also with two-factor authentication.

If enabled, iCloud "Keychain items are transferred from device to device, traveling through Apple servers, but are encrypted in such a way that Apple and other devices can’t read their contents." Keychain Recovery is optional, and in the absence of two-factor, is protected by an iCloud Security Code that only you know.

iMessage is end-to-end encrypted using device-based public-private key pairs: "Apple can’t decrypt the data." Same for FaceTime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that's a vast oversimplification. But anything you write in two sentences about a company as big and multifaceted and long running as Apple would be an oversimplification.

I think if anyone sat down and spent an hour with a panel of experts and chose any 100 privacy decisions and made a scorecard to grade the company, Apple would come out as very strongly pro-individual, have designed dozens of technological features to make privacy both possible and easy by default and that Apple's business model does not profit by deceiving consumers and they furthermore don't profit by collecting and selling information about people.

Apple's model is to sell a premium experience and integrated hardware and not surprise or abuse people so that they are inclined to buy more products - horizontally or vertically for decades to come. Apple's brand is about empowering individuals to make things and do things - not about selling information or even about selling one class of things.

*(p.s. I'll leave all the design decisions about iCloud key escrow, how that is different in China versus the EU versus the US versus 2 years ago vs what may happen next year and how fallible people will be forever when it comes to being operationally proficient at security practices that will block professionals and legal authorities who want to compromise one person's security to another thread.)*